# What would my job location be for remote work on an unemployment form?

Tags: united-states, remote-work, new-york, unemployment-benefits

I am filling out a form for the New York State Department of Labor to apply for unemployment benefits after my work ended with a recruiter. One of the questions asks about my work location.

> If different than your employer's address above, what was the address of your job location or job site?

Since this was a ***remote*** position with a recruiter, what would my job location be? Would it be the recruiter that employed me? The client I was working with? Or my own home address?

Comment: Google it. This can’t be the first time this has come up, given the prevalence of remote work over the past year. And we can’t guess what state DoL policy is.

Comment: @Kaz I could not find an answer on Google, hence why I asked here.

Comment: call them and ask?

Comment: @Kaz When I attempted to call, after navigating the automated system to contact a human, I was told all representatives were busy and they hung up.

Comment: It's unlikely that anybody here is going to understand exactly what the New York State Department of Labor is expecting. It's somewhat unlikely that the recruiter was your employer. Did you paychecks come from the recruiter or the "client"?

Comment: Checks came from the recruiter

Comment: I don't think this is within the scope of workplace.SE. Try law.SE? Or try calling the NY DOL again?

Comment: @Kaz Benefit systems consider every person dealt with to be a defeat. Calling them is nigh impossible.

Comment: @studoku I know, but it’s not as if we can help either. We’ll just be guessing.

Comment: What type of contract did you have? If you are a contractor than your home address if an employee the recruiters address. It's all in your contract. If you don't have contract you can't claim it as an employment.

Answer (score 4):

I have no knowledge of labor law, but I speak English and I'm a New York resident. It sure sounds to me like, in your case, your job site is your home address. It is the physical location where you do your job.

Additional attempted clarification from [Colors-newyork.com](https://colors-newyork.com/what-was-your-job-location-or-job-site-unemployment/):

> **What was your job location or job site unemployment?**
>
> Answer Expert Verified During a job interview you may be asked what
> your last job site or job location was. This would be the address of
> the place that you last worked.
>
> **Where is your job location?**
>
> A job’s location usually means where the job is performed. The vast
> majority of jobs are performed in a single, specific location: a
> workplace. In some cases, such as a field technician, the workplace
> varies because the work involves going to various locations and
> provide technical service to support a service.
>
> **What was your job site meaning?**
>
> jobsite (plural jobsites) A physical location where work is done,
> especially construction work.
>
> **What is your work location?**
>
> More Definitions of Work Location Work Location means the street
> address where an employee normally works. Work Location means any
> fixed place of business, office, or plant where employees regularly
> work in the trade or business of the employer.

So if that is correct, then the "physical location where work is done" would be, in the OP's case, their home address.

Comment: What might complicate the author’s answer is if the employer was not in NY.  I would contact someone from the NY Labor Department

Comment: @Donald: I agree that getting the DOL to respond would be great. Note OP says in a comment they've tried that and they don't answer this question. Note also there is a separate question on the form re: "your employer's address above".